# How to get instance values for form in django?

Tags: python, django

I've overridden a detail view so I can render form elements with render_field. However, when rendered they do not show the saved values. I can't set the value in the template because I can't put {{}} within {% %} syntax. How can I access and display the previously saved model instance values? (these are sliders that I want to keep as sliders, and they also have a lot of data attributes that I want to keep consistent, so I can't just write the inputs manually in the template)

In views.py:

```
class MyDetailEditMixin(SingleObjectMixin):
"""
Hybrid mixin to edit a detail
"""
model = MyModel
form_class = forms.MyForm
raise_execption = True
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    expose the form
    """
    kwargs.setdefault('form', forms.MyForm)
    return super(MyDetailEditMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


class MyDetailView(MyDetailEditMixin, DetailView):
    """
    Shows the details
    """
```

I feel like I need to explicitly mention the instance somehow? I'm not sure. The inputs render correctly with all their specific data attributes, just no set values.

Comment: Whoever voted the question down, can you explain why? I'm probably not asking the right question, but I don't know what the right question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many different things, but in the end I ditched the mixin and edited MyDetailView with a get_form method (and within that I could tell it to use the instance):

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
"""
Shows the details
"""

form_class = forms.MyForm

def get_form(self):
    form = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
    return form

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'form': self.form_class(instance=self.get_object()),
    })

    return context
```

The render_field fields have their values filled with the saved instance values and all the attributes they need are there.

Comment: `DetailView` doesn't have a `get_form` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview. Perhaps you want [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) then you can `instance = self.get_form().instance`

Comment: I added one, and it works. I don't need an UpdateView, I really just need a shorthand way of rendering the sliders with pre-filled data attributes, which I have set up already in the form (there are like 12 attributes, and each input is set differently, so it's a hassle to rewrite it in html as well, which also means that having the same info in two places means that it can accidentally diverge).